# Django queryset: cannot filter by current week when USE_TZ is enabled

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django 2.1 with `USE_TZ = True` and `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`.

This is my model DateTimeField:

```
create_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), null=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

I am trying to get the current week results based on the week number. I tried the following:

```
today = timezone.now()
current_week_num = today.isocalendar()[1]
week_results = MyModel.objects.filter(create_date__week=current_week_num).count()
```

This always return 0 while there are records in the database. It works fine if I set `USE_TZ = False`. I'm using a MySql database.

Any idea?

UPDATE:

the problem was with MySQL time_zone table empty! I had to run:
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo
and the problem is gone!

Comment: Iso week starts on Monday. Are you sure it's not just that the records were created last week?

Comment: @HåkenLid I have one record in the database which is 2018-12-17 11:57:28.892100, that is week number 51 (I also tried passing 50 instead of current_week_num but it doesn't change). It works if I set USE_TZ = False.

Comment: I have printed the queries both with USE_TZ true and false. This is what I get with TZ enabled:
WEEK(CONVERT_TZ(`mymodel`.`create_date`, 'UTC', 'UTC'), 3) = 51)

and this with TZ disabled (this is working):
WEEK(`mymodel`.`create_date`, 3) = 51)

Comment: It looks like mysql does not correctly convert from UTC to UTC? I would expect that `CONVERT_TZ` function to not change the input value. Maybe you have to change some timezone settings for your mysql server? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: According to mysql doc, `CONVERT_TZ` might return `NULL` if "the arguments are invalid". It might be what's happening here? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: The problem was that MySQL table time_zone was empty. After running the command mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo it worked! thank you.

Comment: You can write your solution in as an answer and accept it. It's a confusing bug, and I don't know if it's mentioned in the django docs, so it might be helpful for someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what the problem is, basically MySQL time_zone table was empty and needed to be filled out!

After running the following command:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

the problem has gone away!

Answer (score 1):

Section [`Other databases`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#other-databases) at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#database may be of interest if your database is **not** Postgres.

> Other backends store datetimes without time zone information. If you
>   switch from USE_TZ = False to USE_TZ = True, you must convert your
>   data from local time to UTC – which isn’t deterministic if your local
>   time has DST.

Comment: My database is MYSQL, and I am trying to deal with week numbers in my case

Comment: @Giorgio: But did you switch over to `USE_TZ=True` after creating the records? If so, you might have to perform a migration on the datetimes that are already stored in the database.

Comment: @HåkenLid no actually USE_TZ=True has been set from the beginning